# google-play-services_lib in Android project.properties

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services

i have a question relate to Android project.properties. I have no idea how to use this file. I would like to ask what does the sentence mean?

```
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

Inside my Manifest file. I have a sentence as below

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But i can not find a file called "version" which contains resource like this

```
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer>
</resources>
```

everything works fine after i add

```
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

inside project.properties.

could anyone explain what happens? All helps are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using Google Play Services API which are published by Google.

These APIs can be accessed via library. We need to link the google play library to our project. This is done via code:

```
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

or via IDE Eclipse :

`Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Android tab -> Add library`

So now library is linked to your project.

The meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

is defined inside the library which is linked to your project. So, the integer **google_play_services_version** is defined inside the library

I hope this will solve your doubt

Answer (score 0):

You are working with google play services library project in your project.
When you added `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"` in your manifest it is looking for respective resource which is already in google play service lib.

You can do same by using eclipse - project properties - android - add library.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib


* which means your using google play service liberary in your project

* project.properties file is a location for
  defining the android version  which you using 
  to build the app and the liberary reference if any.


 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


 * This for mention the google play service version.there are different versions available
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In Eclipse goto File ⇒ Import ⇒ Android ⇒ Existing Android Code Into Workspace
2. Click on Browse and select Google Play Services project from your android sdk folder. You can locate play services library project from
   android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
3. Add the Google Play Services project as a library to your project. Right click on the project and select properties. In the properties window, on left side select Android. On the right, you can see a Add button under library section. Click it and select google play services library